# Can I get more meaningful file and line information when using set_error_handler?

Tags: php

I've been writing a small PHP framework wherein I've been making use of `set_error_handler` to  display errors in a more useful manner, a pretty typical feature of any framework.

I just finished implementing a feature where, by using the file and line number that are passed to the error handler, I load that line and the ones above and below it into view to show exactly where the problem is:

[image]

This is working nicely, however now that it's implemented I have noticed that this is completely nonhelpful because the line flagged is the line *triggering* the error via `trigger_error` rather than the code actually *causing* the error.

Is there a way to refer to the line causing the error instead? If I could work out where a function call was made that has failed, that would be most ideal. For example, I'd like to be referred to `line 7` in this situation rather than `line 4` like I am currently:

```
1.  function test($value)
2.  {
3.      if($value < 5)
4.          trigger_error("I expected more.");
5.  }
6.  
7.  test(3);
```

I'm happy to modify the methods in my framework that make use of `trigger_error` if that helps (e.g. if there's a way to know where a function is called from within itself (pretty sure there's not), something along those lines).

I am comfortable using an alternative to `set_error_handler` and `trigger_error` if need be.

Comment: You could probably do something with debug_backtrace() or debug_print_backtrace(). You should certainly wrap all your error logging calls in your own function to avoid lots of find and replace, though.

Comment: @IMSoP [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) looks to be at least very close to what I want to achieve - thank you, I'll check it out more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `debug_backtrace` in this case but you need to adjust what you want to track as line of error to your needs. For example in this case:

```
<?php

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');

function test($value)
{
     if($value < 5)
          trigger_error("I expected more.");
}

test(3);     

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{

    $db = debug_backtrace();
    for ($i=0, $c = count($db); $i<$c; ++$i) {
        if ($db[$i]['function'] == 'trigger_error') {
            echo $db[$i+1]['line'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

will give you 11

Comment: That `$i + 1` is really important: the entries in PHP's backtrace arrays always feel off by one to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check out [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).